# Updating a number in pygame

Tags: python, events, time, pygame, screen

i have a rather simple problem. 
I want to update a value once per second, and my code does that. The updated number does show behind the surface, although the order should be right.

How can i make it show on top?

(i drew the circle to see if it is behind or in front of the circle if i do not do screen.fill)

Also, i would appreciate if the numbers would not be drawn on top of each other, but i can solve that myself once the other problem is dealt with.

Code:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
display_width = 1600
display_height = 800

color = 23,52,85
color2 = 43,200,8

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

wood = 0

myFont = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
someEvent = pygame.key.get_pressed()

MOVEEVENT = pygame.USEREVENT+1
t = 1000
pygame.time.set_timer(MOVEEVENT,t)

def increaseWood():
  global wood
  wood+=3
  print("The wood was increased")
  return wood

def drawEverySecond():
  text = "Wood: " + str(increaseWood())
  label = myFont.render(text,1,color2)
  screen.blit(label, (1000,300))
  print('Current Wood:', wood)

while True:
  pygame.display.update()
  screen.fill(color)
  pygame.draw.circle(screen, (220,40,100),(1000,300), 20,4 )
  #drawEverySecond()

  for event in pygame.event.get():
      #print(event)
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          pygame.display.quit()
          quit()
      if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
          print("Mouse was pressed!")
      if event.type == MOVEEVENT:
        drawEverySecond()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to increment the number and to render the `label` Surface once per seconde (every time when `MOVEEVENT` occurs):

```py
label = label = myFont.render("Wood: 0", 1, color2) 
def drawEverySecond():
    global label
    text = "Wood: " + str(increaseWood())
    label = myFont.render(text,1,color2)  
    print('Current Wood:', wood)
```

But you have to draw the `label` Surface in ever frame:

```py
while True:
    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill(color)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (220,40,100),(1000,300), 20,4 )
    screen.blit(label, (1000,300))

    # [...]
```